# Batch file type always shows exe

Tags: batch-file

The batch file type is always taking as exe instead of Shell command.
Even if i delete the exe file association and add batfile association it is not taking. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the file extension to `.bat`.

If you can't see the files' extensions, open a File Explorer and then go to **View Menu**-> **Options...** Then in the **View** Tab of Folder Options Dialog box, Un-check *"Hide extensions for known file types"*.

Then just change the extension from whatever it is to `.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Your *The batch file type is always taking as exe instead of Shell command* statement looks to be a bit unclear.
However, there is no difference or discrimination in the way how the Windows command line interpreter treats default *executables* `.COM`, `.EXE`, `.BAT` and `.CMD`.

**Proof**: next batch script parses the default value of `PathExt` environment variable `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD` and displays appropriate output values from `assoc` and `ftype` commands, respectively:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "parse_ext=%pathext:;=","%"
@for %%G in ("%parse_ext%") do (
  @for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%H in ('assoc %%G') do (
    @for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%J in ('ftype %%I') do (
      @echo %%H %%I     %%K
    )
  ) 
)
```

Output:

```
==>D:\bat\SU\969327.bat
.COM    comfile         "%1" %*
.EXE    exefile         "%1" %*
.BAT    batfile         "%1" %*
.CMD    cmdfile         "%1" %*
```

Fyi: `PathExt` environment variable returns a list of the file extensions that the operating system considers to be *executable*. When executing a command line that does not contain an extension, the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) uses the value of this environment variable to determine which extensions to look for and in what order.